# Why do I keep getting this "name 'Model' is not defined" error in my Django project?

Tags: python, django, model, nameerror

I've looked through the stackoverflow questions under this topic already and I moved my Trainer class to be above my Class_Training class, but I still keep getting the same "name 'Model' is not defined" error when I enter 'manage.py create superuser' on my command prompt.

Also, I am having diffuclty migrating my models. I tried 'django-admin makemigrations training' but django-admin as not recoginised; and 'manage.py makemigrations training' but makemigrations was not recognised.

How do I migrate my models?

Here is my code:

```
    #from django.db import models
 from django_pg import models

# Create your models here.
TRAINING_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('AC', 'Armed Combat'),
    ('UC', 'Unarmed Combat'),
    ('P', 'Piloting'),
    ('O', 'Other'),
)

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('F', 'Female'),
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('U', 'Unspecified'),
    )
OUTCOME_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'Pass'),
    ('F', 'Fail'),
    )

class Trainer(models, Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENDER_CHOICES)
    citizenship = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 30)

class Class_Training(models, Model):
    trainer = models.ForeignKey('Trainer')
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    type_of_class = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices= TRAINING_TYPE_CHOICES)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.class_name, self.trainer


class ReportLog(models.CompositeField):
    class_ID = models.IntegerField
    hero_ID = models.IntegerField
    outcome = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = OUTCOME_CHOICES)
    comments = models.TextField
    trainer = models.IntegerField

    class Meta:
        db_type = 'report'

class Attendance(models.CompositeField):
    class_ID = models.IntegerField
    hero_ID = models.IntegerField
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    date = models.DateField
    start_time = models.TimeField
    end_time = models.TimeField

    class Meta:
        db_type = 'attendance'

class Room(models, Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Hero(models, Model):
    codename = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.codename
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Fixing the issue with `Model`

You have used `models, Model` instead of `models.Model` in some of your model definitions. The `Model` class is in the `model` module. That's why we use a `.` instead of a comma.

Room model:

```
class Room(models.Model):
```

Hero model:

```
class Hero(models.Model):
```

Trainer model:

```
class Trainer(models.Model):
```

And finally:

```
class Class_Training(models.Model):
```

#### Fixing the issue with Migrations

It should be:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

You need `python` command. Also check if you are in the directory where your `manage.py` is.

Comment: I am using the windows command prompt and it doesn't recognise the term 'python'.

Comment: You need to add `python` to your system paths.

Comment: How do I do that? I have Python34 (3.4) in my C drive, as: C:/Python34.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Windows for development for quite sometimes. You can search in Google.

Comment: Okay I've added the python command, and it recognises it now, but 'makemigrations' is still not recognised as a command.

Comment: What version of Django are you on?

Comment: I am using Django 1.6.11

Comment: Okay I have just upgraded to 1.9 and my problem has been solved, and now I have a new problem. I'll just make that a separate question.